# Rally / Bugzilla: syncing "Schedule State" / Status field

Tags: bugzilla, rally

Has anyone used the Rally-Bugzilla connector to sync the state fields (e.g. syncing the Schedule State field within Rally against the status field in Bugzilla - which has values such as "NEW", "EVALUATED", "ASSIGNED", "IN_WORK" etc)?   As I see it, this is complicated by the fact that there isn't a 1:1 relationship between the values across the 2 systems, in which case does anyone have any suggestions on approaches?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally facilitated via a Field Handler in the config.xml for the connector. There's a decent discussion of this at http://www.rallydev.com/help/rally-integrations-faq-and-best-practices#How-to-map-fields. The general idea is this:

```
    <Connector>
       <FieldMapping>
          <Field> <Rally>State</Rally>
                  <Other>BG_STATUS</Other>
          </Field>
          ....
       <OtherFieldHandlers>
          <OtherEnumFieldHandler>
             <FieldName>BG_STATUS</FieldName>
             <Mappings>
                <Field><Rally>Defined</Rally>           <Other>New</Other></Field>
                <Field><Rally>In-Progress</Rally>       <Other>Assigned</Other></Field>
                <!-- Etc -->
             </Mappings>
          </OtherEnumFieldHandler>
    </Connector>
```

Note that you may need to go into the Rally tool to define some custom values for the State field/drop-down in order to accomodate the heuristic mappings of State values in Bugzilla.

Comment: Thanks. To keep things simple for our devs trying out Rally, we wanted to have ScheduleState drive the Bugzilla state, with mappings e.g.
<Field><Rally>Defined</Rally><Other>NEW</Other></Field>
<Field><Rally>Defined</Rally><Other>EVALUATED</Other></Field>
<Field><Rally>In-Progress</Rally><Other>IN_WORK</Other></Field>
etc (so a ScheduleState change would set the Bz bug to "IN_WORK").  But a Bz bug could come into Rally (with ScheduleState being set), then someone changes the Rally defect (e.g. description) & the defect gets synced back to Bz, potentially changing the Bz state unnecessarily.